# Why is MessagingCenter.Subscribe not changing the value of my property?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to send an argument via Messagingcenter, but it is not changing the Name property's value. I am new to xamarin and especially MVVM, so if this is part of `MessagingCenter.Subscribe`'s behavior, please let me know.

Code:

MainPage

```
        public async void ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var details = e.Item as ClassListModel;

            MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, ClassListModel>(this, "ClassDetails", details);

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ClassPage());
        }
```

ClassPageViewModel

```
public string Name { get; set; }

        public ClassPageViewModel()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, ClassListModel>(this, "ClassDetails", (sender, arg) => 
            {
                Name = arg.Name;
            });        
        }
```

`Name` is still null. Any ideas?

Comment: you appear to be sending a message **before** you subscribe to it.  If you are just trying to pass a parameter to ClassPage, using the constructor would be much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here not recommanding to use **MessagingCenter** to pass data to next page . The better **solution** that can pass an argument (`ClassListModel`) of **ClassPage** directly .

Modify `ItemTapped` as follow :

```
public async void ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var details = e.Item as ClassListModel;

    //MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, ClassListModel>(this, "ClassDetails", details);

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ClassPage(details));
}
```

In **ClassPage** constructor method modified as follow :

```
public ClassPage(ClassListModel model)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = model;
}
```

If *Xaml* of **ClassPage** defined as follow , it will work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="AppListViewCheck.ClassPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The effect :

[image]

===========================Update==========================

You need to call `MessagingCenter.Send` after `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` , not before that .

Such as follow :

```
 public async void ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
 {
    var details = e.Item as ClassListModel;

    // Add this line , ClassPageViewModel will fire MessagingCenter.Subscribe
    ClassPageViewModel classPageViewModel = new ClassPageViewModel();

    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, ClassListModel>(this, "ClassDetails", details);

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ClassPage());
 }
```

Then you can test as follow :

```
public class ClassPageViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ClassPageViewModel()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, CellClass>(this, "ClassDetails", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            Name = arg.Name;
            Console.WriteLine("---"+arg.Name);
        });
    }
}
```

If **ClassPageViewModel** has been uesd for other page , and want to update view when runtime , you need to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` for it . More mvvm used refer to this docment : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: I don't think I can use a constructor here, as the next page is a Tabbedpage. I need to get the information to the viewmodel, which all pages in the Tabbedpage are bound to. Thus the information can reach all of these pages at once. 

But your first few sentences helped me find something else that may work.
`           
            var nextpage = new ClassMainPage
            {
                BindingContext = new ClassPageViewModel
                {
                    Name = details.Name
                }
            };
`
(This is inside ItemTapped)

Comment: (continuation of previous comment due to character limit)
However, Name is still null.

Comment: @PurpleSprinkles Sorry for not too much understanding why the scene need `MessagingCenter` to pass value to `ViewModel` . . I will update answer to explain that .